# Seleccionar solo el texto de etiqueta xml con xslt

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

Tengo el siguiente xml:

```
<partido>Ha ganado el barcelona
                <equipos>
                    <nombre>Barcelona el liverpool</nom>
                    <resultado>3-0</resultado>
                </equipos>
 </partido>
```

Quiero con el xslt sacar el texto Ha ganado el Barcelona és decir el texto de la etiqueta partido pero solo eso no quiero que salga el texto que hay dentro de equipos.

He echo el siguiente value-of select.

```
<conclusion><xsl:value-of select="partido"/></conclusion>
```

Pero el resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

```
<conclusion>
Ha ganado el barcelona

                       Barcelona el liverpool
                      3-0

</conclusion>
```

Como puedo hacer para que solo me muestre lo que quiero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error al cerrar el nodo `nombre`, aunque entiendo que habrá sido por copiar el código en la pregunta, en cualquier caso sería:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partido>Ha ganado el barcelona
    <equipos>
        <nombre>Barcelona el liverpool</nombre>
        <resultado>3-0</resultado>
    </equipos>
</partido>
```

Y luego para que sólo salga `Ha ganado el barcelona` te bastaría con usar `text()` con el nodo `partido`, porque como lo estás haciendo ahora, saldrá todo lo de ese nodo y sus hijos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
             <body>
                 <conclusion>
                     <xsl:value-of select="partido/text()"/>
                 </conclusion>
             </body>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```